# Listing all directories from s3 using s3 client Java (Answer)

Tags: java, amazon-s3, directory, aws-s3-client

I wanted to list directories under a particular bucket but S3client does not return directories  but objects
I have been struggling with this I couldn't find anything on google but after some research i got my answers so i thought to put my solution here

```
private static List<String> listDirectoryFromS3FS(URI baseURI)
{
    UnderFsObjectMeta underFsObjectMeta = new UnderFsObjectMeta(baseURI);
    S3Client client = S3Client.builder().region(Region.US_EAST_1).build();
    ListObjectsV2Request request = ListObjectsV2Request.builder().bucket(underFsObjectMeta.m_sBucketName)
            .prefix(underFsObjectMeta.m_sDirectoryPath).delimiter(Utility.PART_FILE_SEPARATOR).build();
    List<CommonPrefix> prefixes = client.listObjectsV2(request).commonPrefixes();

    List<String> listDirectories = new LinkedList<>();
    for (CommonPrefix prefix:prefixes)
    {
        listDirectories.add(prefix.prefix());

    }

    return listDirectories;
}
```

Comment: The answer should be posted separately, in the answer section.